# Datetime 'Conversion failed' error when using CASE comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, case, type-conversion

I have a table that stores Field/Value pairs for comparison, such as:

```
ID    FieldName    ValueA      ValueB
----  ----------   -------     ------
1     Name         ABC         XYZ
1     StartDate    2015-05-04  2015-06-05
1     Amount       4           4
2     Name         DEF         UVW
2     StartDate    2015-03-22  2015-02-11
2     Amount       4           4
```

I am trying to compare the values of ValueA and ValueB, looking for mismatched values. Since they are stored as varchar(max) in the table, sometimes mismatches will come up where they shouldn't, i.e.

```
ID    FieldName    ValueA      ValueB
----  ----------   -------     ------
3     StartDate    2015-01-30  01/30/2015
```

so I use a `CASE` statement to convert the datatype before comparison, i.e.

```
Select *
From ComparisonTable
where
(case when FieldName = 'StartDate' then CAST(ValueA as datetime)
      when FieldName = 'Amount' then CAST(ValueA as int)
      else CAST(ValueA as varchar(max))
 end)
=
(case when FieldName = 'StartDate' then CAST(ValueB as datetime)
      when FieldName = 'Amount' then CAST(ValueB as int)
      else CAST(ValueB as varchar(max))
 end)
```

I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

I figured this was because somewhere, a StartDate value had been incorrectly entered. However, I did the following search:

```
Select *
From ComparisonTable
where FieldName = 'StartDate'
and
(ISDATE(ValueA) = 0
OR
ISDATE(ValueB) = 0)
```

and nothing came up which, to me, says that all the date values are stored properly.

I am wondering if anybody else has faced a similar issue, or if there is something inherent in SQL/SQL Server that does not allow these types of datatype conversions in a `WHERE/CASE` statement?

**UPDATE**
I tried using the same `CASE` in a simple `SELECT`:

```
SELECT
    (case when FieldName = 'StartDate' then CAST(ValueA as datetime)
          when FieldName = 'Amount' then CAST(ValueA as int)
          else CAST(ValueA as varchar(max))
     end)
    =
    (case when FieldName = 'StartDate' then CAST(ValueB as datetime)
          when FieldName = 'Amount' then CAST(ValueB as int)
          else CAST(ValueB as varchar(max))
     end)
WHERE FieldName IN ('StartDate','Amount')
```

and EVERYTHING came back as datetime, meaning even the `int` values were converted into dates, which leads me to believe that this type of `CASE` casting is not allowed. Even though the `CASE` is saying to convert 'Name' fields to `varchar` it is converting everything to datetime instead.

If this is standard SQL Server behavior, is there any workaround I can use to make these conversions?

Comment: umm... casting `Amount` as `Datetime` seems odd... since it's value is 4 in your example...  Maybe you meant int or numeric?  Suggestion: Double check intended datatype for "Amount"

Comment: You can't mix datatypes like that in a case expression. It will follow the datatype precedence rules and attempt to convert everything to a datetime. This one of the challenging parts of using EAV and not doing it quite right. In your query you would have to convert everything to a character datatype to get this to work.

Comment: @xQbert that was a copy/paste typo. They are being converted to `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I came up with is to use `UNION ALL` to separate the different types:

```
SELECT *
FROM ComparisonTable
WHERE FieldName = 'StartDate'
AND CAST(ValueA as datetime) = CAST(ValueB as datetime)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM ComparisonTable
WHERE FieldName = 'Amount'
AND CAST(ValueA as int) = CAST(ValueB as int)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM ComparisonTable
WHERE FieldName = 'Name'
AND CAST(ValueA as varchar(max)) = CAST(ValueB as varchar(max))
```

It works, but I will compare it against other methods for efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

I see what you're trying to do, but you can't use multiple types for a single value like that.  They will all need to be the same datatype to do it the way you're trying.

This should do what you want, but this will result in poor performance, as no index can be used for this type of comparison.

```
Select  *
From    ComparisonTable
Where   
(
    FieldName = 'StartDate'
And Cast(ValueA As DateTime) = Cast(ValueB As DateTime)
)
Or
(
    FieldName = 'Amount'
And Cast(ValueA As Int) = Cast(ValueB As Int)
)
Or
(
    FieldName Not In ('StartDate', 'Amount')
And Cast(ValueA As Varchar (Max)) = Cast(ValueB As Varchar (Max))
)
```

Another option would be to convert everything to `VARCHAR` after the datatype conversion:

```
Select  *
From    ComparisonTable
Where   
(
    case    
        when FieldName = 'StartDate' then CAST(CAST(ValueA as datetime) As Varchar (Max))
        when FieldName = 'Amount' then CAST(CAST(ValueA as int) AS Varchar (Max))
        else CAST(ValueA as varchar(max))
    end
)
=
(
    case 
        when FieldName = 'StartDate' then CAST(CAST(ValueB as datetime) AS Varchar(Max))
        when FieldName = 'Amount' then CAST(CAST(ValueB as int) As Varchar (Max))
        else CAST(ValueB as varchar(max))
    end
)
```